# Spliting a big table by category into smaller ones

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that uses EF Core. I have multiple seller types (doctor / styler), all having the same model i.e. id, name, location.

I was thinking that instead of pushing every seller into a `seller` table and add a `category` column to categories them, to have a base model class that each seller is going to inherit from, and have each seller type in his table (for performance reasons on large databases).

Ex: if I want a doctor I query only the doctor table not the whole seller table.

Now my problem is that I want to do this from a `SellerController` that receives only `Seller` objects and inside it I would like to cast them into doctor/styler models to use the right table.

But how can I do this?

Like beside a giant switch case in each endpoint of my controller. I thought that I could build a convertor that receives a `Seller` object and returns a doctor/styler object but what should that return type be then?

Old

```
public class Stylist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }
}

public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }
}
```

New

```
public class BaseSeller
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }
}
    
public class Stylist : BaseSeller
{

}
    
public class Stylist : BaseSeller
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this,pass BaseSeller and the ClassName which you want to convert to:

```
public Object ConvertBaseSeller(BaseSeller Seller,string ClassName) {
            if (ClassName == "Stylist")
            {
                Stylist s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stylist>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Seller));
                return s;
            }
            else{
                Doctor d= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Doctor>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Seller));
                return d;
            }
            
        }
```

and then call it like this:

```
var s = ConvertBaseSeller(new BaseSeller(), "Doctor");
```